# OpenCart Redirecting to Upgrade (install/index.php) after successful installation while clicking the view store/admin page

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, opencart, opencart2.x

I am newbie in Opencart,
I have successfully installed Opencart latest version(2.0.2.0) on my localhost using XAMPP (Apache & MySQL) but while I click the view my store or Login to admin portal link from success page it takes me to http://localhost/mysite/install/index.php Page and asks me upgrade.

Initially I was on a lower version and performed this up-gradation successfully but was redirecting me to this page in a loop, so i made this fresh installation but facing the same problem every time..
Please guide where i am doing wrong.

regards-
Saniun

Comment: Try deleting your install directory and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: ya I tried that earlier, it didn't work, was getting error, However I have uninstalled all my workplaces, XAMPP, openCart ETC and installed defining new port set and its now working fine. However while the installation was over have removed the Install directory as suggested, thanks..

Comment: What paths and urls are defined in your `config.php` files?  Do the *view my store* & *Login to admin* links point to *mysite/install* or are you actually being redirected there?  If, the latter, what is the actual link?

Comment: My config.php was pointing to the view my store and admin links, still i was getting the error. However i have fixed it by the process i mentioned above.